# how to get http: request to work in an electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am still new to electron and nodejs but am wanting to do this project. I would like to open google in an http: request(url, response, body) and store the html  contents in an array.

here is a code example I tried.

```
function website(){
   var content=[];
   var request = require('request')

   var url = 'http://www.google.com'

   function goog(callback) {
       request(url, function(error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              content.push(body);
          }
       })
            callback(content);
   }

 }
```

I placed a module.exports = website; at the bottom to export it back to the index.html page.

I know I am missing some basic fundamentals but hopefully someone could give me some good directions to help me complete the task and learn.

Please state things in a step by step easy to understand way.

Thanks

Comment: Not too familiar with electron, but a couple things I noticed. `function` is a reserved keyword, so you can't do things like `function = `, which may just be a typo, but you need to do it like, `function website() {`, or `var website = function() {`. You're also not defining your callback function anywhere in the code you posted, and you're not calling your `goog()` anywhere, but you may be somewhere else so posting the rest of your code may help.

Comment: function = is my mistake  the call back is content and it will be callback in the index.html file.

Comment: Gonna check for a other solution and gonna post to you.